# Connect to VMware host from VMware guest with Juniper VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, vmware-player, juniper

My company provide remote access to its private network using Juniper Connect. They have restricted to the Windows Juniper Connect client, but I need to work into a GNU/Linux distribution.

Before upgrading VMWare Player from 4.X to the latest 6 version, I was able to do the following:

1. Open the VPN connection
2. Connect with a SSH client from Windows to a computer inside my company network, opening some tunnels (something like `-L0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22`).
3. Launch a VM guest with two network interfaces: a bridged one and a NAT one
4. From the guest, use SSH to connect to the tunnel defined in step 2, using the NAT gateway IP

But after upgrading, I cannot access using the same method. I tried to forward the ports to the host's one, but it doesn't work.

The problem only happens when the VPN is connected: I don't have any access from my LAN network to the Windows host, but I can access to the bridge interface into the GNU/Linux guest, as usual.

Is there some way to forward all the ports from the NAT to the same host (in this case, to the Windows native OS)?

P.S. I tried changing the metrics of the VPN connection, but when I change that parameter, the VPN auto-reconnect and recover its previous metrics value

Comment: Have you asked your IT department for assistance? Your version of VMWare is very unlikely the direct cause of your problems.

Comment: I don't think VMware is the cause of my problem, but my IT department don't give assistance for external contractors like me

Comment: Have you tried using VMWare Player 4.x (again) to see if you can get it working again?  It seems sort of short sighted to not help contractors with technical question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I think it is a VMware configuration stuff, and reinstalling 4.x won't help me much because I lost the configuration itself... I will try at the end of the day. Thanks for your interest. :-)